# Car is dead, but battery is (apparently) fully charged?

Tags: electrical, battery, starting

My car seems to be completely dead (no dash/radio/lights/ignition/key remote lock) but after testing with a battery charged apparently the battery is completely full. I've tested while connecting to both battery terminals and the further down the cables, cleaned the terminals and checked all fuses, and everything seems to be ok. Could this be some cabling problems down the circuit or could there any other explanation for it?

EDIT: It's a 2003 Honda Jazz. I tested with the battery charger, I am assuming it is impossible to get a false positive unless the battery is indeed charged. The fuses I just looked at them, but I doubt it's a fuse issue as nothing works, they would all need to be fried.

Comment: Make, Model, Year and Engine please?

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: Did you check the numerous ground connections that today's motor vehicles implement? There's going to be at least one to the frame, one to the engine block and who knows how many more!

Comment: @Moab It's a 2003 Honda Jazz

Comment: @HandyHowie I used the battery charger by placing the (-) connector to the chassis

Comment: @fred_dot_u How do I know exactly where they are? the ground from the battery connects directly to the chassis, but I can't see any other connection.

Comment: That's the fun of finding those earthing or grounding points - you have to look for them...

Comment: Try using some jump leads to another battery to see if that helps.